# Android Studio 3.1.4 throw ERROR Start Failed

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-14, android-studio-3.1.4

I got this below Error while opening ***Android Studio 3.1.4***
[image]

i tried below solution but still facing same **ERROR**

1->Refer This [link](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000448004-Intellij-Idea-doesn-t-start).

2->Delete Plugin folder manually.

Comment: File -> Invalidate and restart

Comment: but i can't open Any android project i got error while opening android studio

Comment: Reinstall your studio

Comment: Any other option out of this solution **Reinstall your studio**?

Comment: No you have to do this otherwise reinstall your SDK

Comment: @AbhinavGupta okay i'll install latest version of Android studio

Comment: @AbhinavGupta thanks issue resolved after installing latest version of Android studio

Comment: What wrong with question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this error is occurred because some plugins are not download properly

so please uninstall this android studio and reinstall new android studio and you have to a better network speed to download all plugins properly

this is work for me

Comment: yes after install latest version its also work for me

Answer (score 1):

install Android Studio 3.2 ...and **don't** import (the corrupted) settings from 3.1.

Comment: sure i'll keep it in mind while install latest version of android studio

Comment: i do it same way Reinstall Android studio without checking on import